# An explanation for sketching the graph of the family of circles: $x^2+y^2=2cx $

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

I found in the internet a graph for the family of circles: $x^2+y^2=2cx $ and I'm not sure I quite understood if its true or I would be able to draw it by myself. this is the graph:

[image]

Aren't the center of the circles should be in $(0,0)$? and I'm aware of the symmetry because of the negative and positive values. but if this is the right graph, why is it really true? is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: Think of it as $(x-c)^2 + y^2 = c^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The centers of the circles should be $(c, 0)$, which you can see if you rewrite your equation as follows:
$$
(x-c)^2 + y^2 = x^2-2xc + c^2 + y^2 = (x^2-2xc + y^2)  + c^2 = c^2
$$

Comment: okay, thanks. what about $y=cy^2+cx^2$ ? can I say that this family of circles depend of the value $y$ if its positive or negative and for this reason the whole Circle is above the $x$ axis ?

Comment: In that case you can rewrite it as $x^2+y^2 = y/c$ for nonzero $c$, which is similar to the original question.

Comment: so I understand that $y$ can't be negative if $C$ isn't negative?

Comment: Yes, the corresponding families should be a reflection of the figure in the question across the line $x=y$ (along with the degenerate solution $y=0$ for $c = 0$).